# Require file in Cypress using string templates

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to require a js file in cypress and it works with a static string but as soon as I try string templates, it no longer finds the file.

```
        const page = require('../../cypress/model/page/web/app/Homepage.js');
      //const page = require(`../../cypress/model/page/web/app/${pageName}.js`);
```

Comment: Perhaps the path is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As @ pavelsaman already commented, you should first check what is in pagename. simply a console.log(pagename). Maybe you can find the error here.

If pagename looks good you can try with concatination:

```
pageName = 'somePage' + '.js';
const page = require('../../cypress/model/page/web/app/' + pageName);
```

Comment: Why should `pageName = 'somePage' + '.js';` solve the problem? The OP says the problem is the file could not be found, it will likely not be because of missing concatenation.

Comment: @pavelsaman But he also said that it works when he hard codes it in. 
You are probably right. I also suspect that the page name is wrong (whitespace, or file extension already included.) I'll update my answer in this regard.